# Xcode Nav Bar Button Alignment

Tags: swift, xcode, navbar, xcode-storyboard

I have a navigation bar with 3 left bar buttons (icons), and 1 right bar button (BACK).

The right bar (BACK) button stays far right at all times as I wish.

The 3 left bar buttons are unequally aligned as per image:

[image: Nav bar]

I want them to either: all stay left, or be spaced equally in the remaining space.

I've set the width for each icon to be 50px with a 10px inset either side. However it seems that the 2nd and 3rd buttons (document and star icons) follow these rules, but the 1st (link icon) then just takes up all remaining space.

Looked around but can't see a way of setting the alignment / spacing. Nay help greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

From now on please be sure to post your code when asking a question because it is hard to understand the problem without seeing it.

By the way here is the code for TabBarController class that also has contentInsets
It works perfectly in each of my apps

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    
         override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
               
                let firstVeiwController = createNavController(vc: ExercisesLobby(), selected: UIImage(named: "Note")!, unselected: UIImage(named: "NoteUnselected")!)
                let secondViewController = createNavController(vc: TrainingPlansViewController(), selected: UIImage(named: "Exercises")!, unselected: UIImage(named: "ExercisesUnselected")!)
                let thirdViewController = createNavController(vc: MapViewController(), selected: UIImage(named: "Map")!, unselected: UIImage(named: "MapUnselected")!)
            
                viewControllers = [firstVeiwController, secondViewController, thirdViewController]
                tabBar.barStyle = .black
                tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
                tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
                tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
                additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            
                guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
                
                for item in items {
                    item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 0, bottom: -22, right: 0)
                }
            
            selectedViewController = secondViewController
                
            }
            
            //MARK: - Functions
            
    
           
        }

    extension UITabBarController {
        func createNavController(vc: UIViewController, selected: UIImage, unselected: UIImage) -> UINavigationController {
            
            let viewController = vc
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
            navController.tabBarItem.image = unselected
            navController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selected
            
            return navController
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Aisultan, thanks for reply. Note I didn’t include code as all done via storyboard, thus no code. I’ve added width and inserts via storyboard with no effect. Not sure how doing this via code would be different, but I’ll give it a go.